# Why can't I Transfer ERC20 Tokens through my ERC721 contract as payment?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, erc-721, interfaces

Here's the function:

```
function transferERC20() external {
        _erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, erc20Recipient, 6*10**18);
    }
```

After I imported the IERC20 Interface to interact with ERC20 tokens inside my contract in order to pay for certain functions using the ERC20 instead of ETH Value, I'm always left with a gas estimation error instead of a successful transfer. the balance of function works fine.

```
function getErc20Balance() external view returns(uint){
        uint balance = _erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender) / 1000000000000000000;
        return balance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* set up a contract to accept ERC-20 as payment for ERC-721 tokens.

Here is a demonstration of that technique

https://github.com/fulldecent/spend-ERC20-create-ERC721

Comment: Could you please walk me through that code? I consider myself a beginner and I'm a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: You bet, I have set up a Community Service Hour each week to go through projects like this. Please check out at https://phor.net/#speaking